# Sorting an arraylist with integers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a collection of strings in an array like this:

```
ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();
```

That stores:

```
collection: ["(,0,D=1", "(,1,D=2", "),2,D=2", "),3,D=1", "(,4,D=1", "(,5,D=2", "),6,D=2", "),7,D=1"]
```

I have a lot of d=1 and d=2, as you can see. How do I organize this from 1 first to 2? I tried to use a for loop but the list can contain an infinite number of d=x's. Can you help me organize?

Also, please help me so I don't change the ORDER of any numbers. Example:

```
collection: ["(,0,D=1", "),3,D=1", "(,4,D=1", "),7,D=1", "(,1,D=2", "),2,D=2", "(,5,D=2", "),6,D=2"]
```

So like, every parentheses will be aligned.

I should note that collection[0] = "(,0,D=1"

Comment: This seems specific to a language, please add it to the tags.

Comment: The question is very unclear. You say it's a list of strings, but the example doesn't show what those strings are.  Try `collection[0]="..."`, `collection[1]="..."`, ...

Comment: its storing three variables, that character, the integer, and the depth of D=x. So the entire string is "(,0,D=1",

Comment: i just want to organize starting from d=1 or d=2. but also allow infinite d=x's.

Comment: `(,0,D=1, (,1,D=2, ),2,D=2, ),3,D=1, (,4,D=1, (,5,D=2, ),6,D=2, ),7,D=1` which `,` and `(` are literal and which is not.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: And how would you like to sort them? Give us an expected result

Comment: From your example, `"(,5,D=2", "),6,D=2"` contains 2 "d=x" pattern. How it should be handled?

Comment: from left to right, in order, so the the parentheses match. "(" ")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to do the sorting. A Comparator is a sorting algorithms that you define for your application which written in programming language. Give [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) a Comparator basically you teach Java how you want to sort the list. And it will sort the list for you.
This implementation is based on the following assumptions:

1. The comparison will only take effect on the first `D=x` pattern, subsequent will be ignored.
2. Element is sorted in ascending order base on `x`.
3. Elements do not have `D=x` will be placed at the back

```java
class DeeEqualComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private static final String REGEX = "D=([0-9])+";

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        // find a D=x pattern from the element
        Matcher s1Matcher = Pattern.compile(REGEX).matcher(s1);
        Matcher s2Matcher = Pattern.compile(REGEX).matcher(s2);

        boolean s1Match = s1Matcher.find();
        boolean s2Match = s2Matcher.find();

        if (s1Match && s2Match) {
            // if match is found on s1 and s2, return their integer comparison result
            Integer i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1Matcher.group(1));
            Integer i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2Matcher.group(1));
            return i1.compareTo(i2);
        } else if (s1Match) {
            // if only s1 found a match
            return -1;
        } else if (s2Match) {
            // if only s2 found a match
            return 1;
        } else {
            // if no match is found on both, return their string comparison result
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }

    }
```

Test run

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {
                // provided example
                "(,0,D=1", "(,1,D=2", "),2,D=2", "),3,D=1", "(,4,D=1", "(,5,D=2", "),6,D=2", "),7,D=1"
                // extra test case
                , "exception-5", "exception-0", "D=68" };

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);

        Collections.sort(list, new DeeEqualComparator());

        System.out.print(list);
    }
```

output

```
[(,0,D=1, ),3,D=1, (,4,D=1, ),7,D=1, (,1,D=2, ),2,D=2, (,5,D=2, ),6,D=2, D=68, exception-0, exception-5]
```

Comment: Thanks much man! I was looking into collection and I had a problem with the abc sortment but this is definitly a new way of using the sorting tool.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a class for the items, not a string, e.g. Class Item {char c; int i; int depth;} and ArrayList. Then you can easily sort the list with a custom Comparator.

Comment: All im doing is looking for d=1 to d=x and sort them ascending order. I don't need to add class complications to a simple array that I already have...

Comment: Because if i had an array 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1 All im asking is to sort is like 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2. Why do I need a class for that?

Comment: I also never said the problem was simple. What your saying is complicated for me because I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: Class is not meant to add complexity. A proper OO modeling could reduce complexity yet provide flexibility, as long as it is not over-engineered.